# Websphere IBM MQ connection leaks causing blocked threads

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, classloader

Getting below MQ connection stack trace in Websphere Connection leak trace logs. Not sure why Websphere not releasing connection in within configured timeout. Took

We have MQ JMS pool connection timeout of 5 second configured in the WAS JMS pool setting.

Not able to understand why still connection is in use. We are closing connection using finally code block when we read JMS message. There in no other application error logs.

Used WAS tracing string as -->  *=info: JMSApi=all: JMSServer=all: Messaging=all: JMS_WASTraceAdapter=all: com.ibm.mq.*=all: jmsApi=all: ConnLeakLogic=all: com.ibm.ejs.j2c.*=all

```
Connection marked to be destroyed.  Waiting for transaction end and connection close - MCWrapper id 53b353b3  Managed connection com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection@29422942
        managed connection factory = com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory@70a470a4
        physical connection = com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection@44504450
        connectorName = JMS$MIUFACTORY$JMSManagedConnection@11
        credential = null
        open connection handles = [com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionHandle@655a655a]  State:STATE_ACTIVE_INUSE Thread Id: 0000005f Thread Name: WebContainer : 5 Handle count 1 Start time inuse Wed Jan 18 16:00:18 GMT 2023 Time inuse 1479 (seconds)
    Connection marked to be destroyed.  Waiting for transaction end and connection close - MCWrapper id 270b270b  Managed connection com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection@1c921c92
        managed connection factory = com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory@70a470a4
        physical connection = com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection@3c933c93
        connectorName = JMS$MIUFACTORY$JMSManagedConnection@7
        credential = null
        open connection handles = [com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionHandle@1c2f1c2f]  State:STATE_ACTIVE_INUSE Thread Id: 00000035 Thread Name: WebContainer : 2 Handle count 1 Start time inuse Wed Jan 18 15:24:28 GMT 2023 Time inuse 3629 (seconds)
  Total number of connection in unshared pool: 2 Connection Leak Logic Information:
  MCWrapper id 53b353b3  Managed connection com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedQueueConnection@29422942
        managed connection factory = com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory@70a470a4
        physical connection = com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection@44504450
        connectorName = JMS$MIUFACTORY$JMSManagedConnection@11
        credential = null
        open connection handles = [com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionHandle@655a655a]  State:STATE_ACTIVE_INUSE Thread Id: 0000005f Thread Name: WebContainer : 5 Handle count 1
     Start time inuse Wed Jan 18 16:00:18 GMT 2023 Time inuse 1479 (seconds)
     Last allocation time Wed Jan 18 16:00:18 GMT 2023
       getConnection stack trace information:
          com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:900)
          com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.createQueueConnection(JMSQueueConnectionFactoryHandle.java:84)
```

Websphere verion details:
Version                  7.0.0.45
MQ version:
Implementation-Title: WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter
Implementation-Version: 7.0.1.14

EDIT:
After analysis this connection leak is due to the failed class loading in during one of the service execution.
Even though our library is present in the EAR it is still giving error in loading ClassNotFoundException for loading class which is present in one the jar.
::java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: :

```
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:457): 
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:201):  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:676):   
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:112):  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:642):   
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62):   
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58):   
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:545):  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:642):   
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:513):  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:642):   
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:545):  
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:642):   
at
```

Answer (score 0):

These connection leaks are due to the long running WebSphere long running transactions causing threads to be active and in turn not closing connection handle.